# magento 2 Customer Report unable to set Interval(Period like 2019), Customer Group, Numbers of Orders, Average Order Amount, Total Order Amount

Tags: magento2, custom-reports

I am trying to create custom report and want to display admin grid with columns as below: 
**Interval(Period),Customer Group,Numbers of Orders,Average Order Amount,Total Order Amount**

I have run the query in sql as below.

> SELECT customer_group.customer_group_code as customergroup ,count(sales_order.entity_id) as totalorder,AVG(sales_order.base_grand_total) as avgorder, sum(sales_order.base_grand_total) as grandtotal FROM sales_order,customer_group where customer_group.customer_group_id=sales_order.customer_group_id GROUP BY sales_order.customer_group_id

Below is the output:

[image]

I got the result with data. Just unable to set these in collection and display in admin grid.Below is the code of `collection.php`

```
 <?php namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold;
class Collection extends \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
{
    /**
     * Set Date range to collection
     *
     * @param int $from
     * @param int $to
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDateRange($from, $to)
    {
        $this->_reset()->addAttributeToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addOrderedQty(
            $from,
            $to
        )->setOrder('ordered_qty',self::SORT_ORDER_DESC);
        return $this;
    }


    public function addOrderedQty($from = '', $to = '')
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $orderTableAliasName = $connection->quoteIdentifier('order');

        $orderJoinCondition = [
            $orderTableAliasName . '.entity_id = order_items.order_id',
            $connection->quoteInto("{$orderTableAliasName}.state <> ?", \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED),
        ];

        if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
            $fieldName = $orderTableAliasName . '.created_at';
            $orderJoinCondition[] = $this->prepareBetweenSql($fieldName, $from, $to);
        }

    //here I am unable to get the collection
    $this->getSelect()->reset()->from(
        ['order' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
        ['totalorder' => 'count(sales_order.entity_id)', 
            'avgorder' => 'AVG(sales_order.base_grand_total)',
            'grandtotal' => 'sum(sales_order.base_grand_total)' ],
            implode(' AND ', $orderJoinCondition)
    )->joinInner(
        ['customer' => $this->getTable('customer_group')],
        ['customercode' => 'customer.customer_group_code']
    )->where(
        'customer.customer_group_id=order.customer_group_id'
    )->group(
        'order.customer_group_id'
    );



    return $this;
}


public function setStoreIds($storeIds)
{
    if ($storeIds) {
        $this->getSelect()->where('order_items.store_id IN (?)', (array)$storeIds);
    }
    return $this;
}


public function setOrder($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
{
    if (in_array($attribute, ['orders', 'ordered_qty'])) {
        $this->getSelect()->order($attribute . ' ' . $dir);
    } else {
        parent::setOrder($attribute, $dir);
    }

    return $this;
}


protected function prepareBetweenSql($fieldName, $from, $to)
{
    return sprintf(
        '(%s BETWEEN %s AND %s)',
        $fieldName,
        $this->getConnection()->quote($from),
        $this->getConnection()->quote($to)
    );
} }
```

Comment: Did you try reindex?

Comment: Yes I did already.